# Solving this circuit using node analysis

Tags: voltage, kirchhoffs-laws

Hi I'm having a really bad time in analyzing this [image: circuit]

I can't seem to establish the node equations, I've been reading on articles on how to solve it but the majority use current sources and the methods differ quite a bit, any help is really appreciated.

I know that I have to use KCL on each node, for example for node B I said:

\$ I_{1}+ I_{2} - I_{3} = 0 \$

\$ I_{1} = \dfrac{A-B}{220} \$
\$ I_{2} = \dfrac{C-B}{100} \$
\$ I_{3} = \dfrac{B}{330}  \$

**Given that and solving for B**

A = 12 v
C = 4.5 v

\$ \dfrac{A-B}{220} + \dfrac{C-B}{100} - \dfrac{B}{330} = 0  \$

\$ \dfrac{A}{220} - \dfrac{B}{220} + \dfrac{C}{100} - \dfrac{B}{100} - \dfrac{B}{330}  = 0
\$

\$ \dfrac{A}{220} + \dfrac{C}{100} - B ( \dfrac{1}{220} + \dfrac{1}{100} + \dfrac{1}{330}) = 0  \$

\$ \dfrac{A}{220} + \dfrac{C}{100} = \dfrac{B}{\dfrac{1}{220} + \dfrac{1}{100} + \dfrac{1}{330}} \$

B = 650( A/220 + C/100 )

**Substituting A=12, C=4.5**

\$ B = 
  \dfrac{
   \dfrac{A}{220} + \dfrac{C}{100
  } 
  }{ 
   \left( \dfrac{1}{200} + \dfrac{1}{330} + \dfrac{1}{100} \right)
  } \$

B = 5.66 v

because of independent voltage sources.

I know my problem is on establishing the equations as I don't fully grasp how the analysis is made.

Comment: Come on, you know that 1/220 + 1/100 + 1/330 is not equal to 1/650! Should be \$\dfrac{100 \times 330 + 220 \times 330 + 220 \times 100}{220 \times 100 \times 300} \$

Comment: OMG!!, such a silly mistake... and I kept doing it again and again..

Comment: Replace the 650 by the result of my division and you're there!

Comment: Done, kept making mistakes with the calculator..., \$ B = 5.66 v \$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equations for I1, I2 and I3 are OK, and when you replace A and C with their resp. voltages, you have only 1 variable left: B. Filling in the equations in

\$I1 + I2 - I3 = 0\$

gives you a single linear equation in one variable, which you no doubt can solve. The calculation for D is exactly the same: there's a resistor from A, one from C and one to ground.

Comment: Solving for B I get B= ~64.7 volts, I highly doubt that its the correct voltage..

Comment: No, that's wrong. Intuition says that it must be between 4.5V and 12V. I have the correct solution here on paper. Could you post your equation?

Comment: Off course, I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

In general you not only have to apply KCL but also KVL.

KCL gives you an equation for each node (A, B, C, D, E). The sum of currents in each node is 0
KVL gives you an equation for each loop. The sum of voltages in each loop is zero.

Some of the loops are (see added picture):

1. R1 V1
2. V1 R2 R7
3. R7 R3 V2
4. V2 R8 R6
5. R2 R3 R4
6. R4 R5 R8

[image]

All equations together result in an simultaneous linear equation system for all your currents and all your voltages.

You can solve the linear equation system e.g. by Gaussian Elimination.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "loop"?

Comment: You can perfectly solve this with only KCL. See my answer.

Comment: That is what I did initially, but as my above comment suggests I think that the value is way off.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to edit the image, clears the "loop" question..

Comment: You're unnecessarily complicating things! OP can easily solve this when he combines his equations into his first.

Comment: @stevenvh and Federico Russo: KCL might be enough for this case, but I think it is not complicating  things because this works always: (1) set up equations for all nodes and loops. (2) Solve equation system. (3) Get values for all voltages and currents.

Comment: Solving a set of at least 6 simultaneous equations using Gauss is *always* more complicated than solving a single linear equation.

Comment: @stevenvh: I agree totally for this particular case, but the other approach works in general, no matter how the circuit is connected. Solving it that way is so mechanical that it can be implemented easily in an algorithm. And I think being aware that solving ANY circuit containing only resistors, current and voltage sources (plus L and C if you use complex numbers) is equivalent to solving a set of linear equations is very valuable.